# Check Exchange Quota Usage from Postfix / Prevent Backscatter With Postfix+Exchange

Tags: postfix, exchange

we have some troubles with our Mailsystems at the moment. We have an postfix server, handling all incoming mails and forward them to the correct internal mailsystem. This works well with the most unix MTA's we have build some scripts to prevent any backscatter.

But we have some real issues with the Exchange Systems. We didn't find a way right now to check the available Quota on the Exchange during the incoming SMTPD session phase.

Is there any automatic way to get the total and used quota for a specific user? Is there some information in the ADS we could use for example?

Comment: Hi, did you already have the solution of this problem?